# Python: Curve fitting from data

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am beginner about curve fitting in the Python. I want to fit my data with `curve_fit`. I have 3 data frames and 2 of them contains 3 rows and just one row has float number, others are Nan. My other data frame has 3 float rows. Like that:

```
     MJDMEAN         MJDMEANMAX      LUMINOSITYMAX
0    54960.007130    NaN             NaN
1    55179.630428    55179.630428    7.264769e+40   
2    51884.066424    NaN             NaN
```

I want to create fit from my data. My

```
pf = pd.read_csv('/home/foo/file.csv', sep=',', encoding ='utf-8')
##function is L(t) = Lmax(t)*(((MJDMEAN-(MJDMEANMAX- 100))/(MJDMEANMAX-100))**(-5/3))

def f(x, a, b):
    return a * (((x-(b-100))/(b-100))**(-1.67))
##creating fake data at below:
x = np.linspace((pf['MJDMEANMAX'][1]), (pf['MJDMEANMIN'][0]),10)
y = np.linspace((pf['LUMINOSITYMAX'][1]), (pf['LUMINOSITYMIN'][0]),10)
a, b = pf['LUMINOSITYMAX'][1], pf['MJDMEANMAX'][1]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y)

curvefit = f(x,popt[0],popt[1])
plt.plot (x,y,curvefit)
```

But, I am having blank plot. Ho can I get the fit with that method? I get confused.

Comment: What are the values of `popt[0]` and `popt[1]`?

Comment: popt[0] and popt[1] are a and b from f(x, a, b)

Comment: That's interesting, prints are: 1.0 1.0

Comment: Prints are: popt[0]: 1.0, popt[1]: 1.0, a: 7.26476896915e+40 and b is :55179.6304282

Comment: Have you tried normalizing your values to a scale closer to 1? Fits work best if all parameters are of the same order (say, order 1), and here, there is an order 1e41/5e4 = 2e36 difference. (You should also note that your a and b values are the same as your maximum x & y values.

Comment: My a and b values are just contains contains 2 float numbers in the total. But, x and y has 20 values between minimum and maximums. I get confused more. :(